# Run forfiles.exe as a scheduled task, fails with return code 2147942401

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2019

I'm trying to run forfiles.exe as a scheduled task on a half dozen servers, in order to periodically delete old IIS log files. I have it running as SYSTEM, and I have it set to run with highest privileges. I also tried it with my own admin account, but it failed then as well. I've tried it configured for both Server 2008 R2 and Server 2019, but neither make a difference.

It's running forfiles.exe (including the full path makes no difference), with the following as the argument:

```
Forfiles.exe -p C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1 -m *.log -d -30 -c “Cmd.exe /C del @path\”
```

However, I can run it from the command line/PowerShell without issue (under my own creds, I haven't tried launching PowerShell as system and trying it, but I doubt it would make a difference). I'm also not seeing errors in the event log anywhere, other than in the Task Scheduler section, which just basically shows the return code 2147942401.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Since one person already mentioned it, to be clear, I did try including the full path to forfiles.exe, but that made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

The Task Scheduler requires paths to be fully specified, as it doesn't
have the profile's environment variables.

Use the fully-qualified path : `C:\Windows\System32\forfiles.exe`.

Comment: Like I mentioned though (but I may not have been clear) I tried including the full path, but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: I may have jumped to conclusion, but full-paths should be used in scheduled tasks. Error code 2147942401 is in hex 0x80070001 and it means "Invalid Function". Are you sure that none of the files are being used by IIS? Or that file-names do not contain blanks?

Comment: I don't see how they could be, especially since I tried running it manually on one server via PowerShell without issue, and that same server had been throwing the error when I tried running it via Task Scheduler. And since it's only set to delete log files that are more than 30 days old.

Comment: Perhaps try to debug by doing `echo >> file` of the `cmd` commands that would have been executed. (Will continue tomorrow)

Answer (score 0):

1- Open notepad

2- Put the following line of code in it:

```
start C:\Windows\System32\forfiles.exe -p "C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1" -s -m *.* -d -3 -c "cmd.exe /c del @path"
```

3- Save the file with .bat extension for example `steve-freeman.bat`

4- open task scheduler and create a task

5- in the action tab, browse and choose your batch file.

[image]

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got it, and I feel stupid. I copied the forfiles.exe arguments from a website, and just made the necessary changes (mainly I changed it to 30 days).
But somehow, when it was pasted into the scheduled task, or maybe as a result of something else, the quotation marks LOOKED fine, but were some other type of character. I only noticed this when I added an echo to the command, and the output looked completely messed up. The quotation marks in the output looked like a lowercase O with an accent mark above it. I replaced those with actual quotation marks, tried it again, and it worked perfectly.